# Is it a good idea to remove Relay's connections structure (edges -> node) in a React application? What would be the best approach?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, relay

I have a React app feeded by a django/graphene API serving data with the (facebook) Relay connections structure that i would like to get rid off.

Maybe the best solution would be to do it in the backend but i am not an expert on that so i was thinking to modify all this data in an Apollo response resolver link.

Is this a good idea? What do you think?

Comment: Same question, came from REST and learning GraphQL. The `edges` and `node` structure in the Apollo client response seems redundant to me, especially when I just need the object data similar to the response of a REST API. Unfortunately, I don't see places explaining this much online, perhaps the community and discussion resource online is not yet there, many things that are not clear are not yet documented or discussed. I guess if not possible to do it on the graphene side, I'll do the data transformation in React to remove the edges/node structure. But would love to know the best practice.